# Is it possible to create new News, without inserting new _id? (Mongoose)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to update my document, but when creating a new object, it throws an error, saying that that my existing field already have _id field.

```
        let newNews = new News({
            title: "title
            image: imagePath,
        });

        console.log(newNews); // {_id: "5a3a49d70d9b4d7bab3d9f64", title: "title", image: "./path"}

        const updatedNews = await News.findByIdAndUpdate(ctx.params.id, newNews);

        CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "5a3a4aaaaa3bd47bf62eb9271" at path "_id"
```

How can I create a new News object, without an _id being generated automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update one existing news, you don't need to create the object, just pass the document info in the update method:

```
let newNews = {
            title: "title
            image: imagePath,
        };
```

Rest could be the same